# Method X from Type Y in Assembly Z does not have an Implementation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, typeloadexception

I am very confused!

I have a solution that, when published and deployed gives the me the following error:

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: HttpException 
Exception message: Method 'GetDemosSubsidiaryById' in type 'DG.Crm.DataAccess.Crm2011WS.Repositories.ReferenceEntitiesRepository' from assembly 'DG.Crm.DataAccess.Crm2011WS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
<stack trace>
```

Obviously it builds fine and the method is implemented and definitely exists in the library. I have used reflector to check the deployed DLLs and I can't see anything out of the ordinary there either - classes exist, types are there, method is implemented. The particular method it is complaining about isn't even called, either.

I have removed all references and readded them in the solution.

I have recreated `DG.Crm.DataAccess.Crm2011WS.Repositories.ReferenceEntitiesRepository` by using the the 'Implement Interface' shortcut in Visual Studio.

The solution loads and works fine from within Visual Studio.

What am I missing here or where else can I look for more information?

edit to add on solution structure:

[image]

The `2011WS` library implements interfaces that live in the `Common` library. Both are then referenced by the WebApps MVC web application.

Comment: is that your assembly DG.Crm.DataAccess.Crm2011WS? Did you check that the given method is implemented? Are your assemblies coming from GAC?

Comment: Dumb question, but did you verify that the .NET version specified in IIS matches the version used in your project?

Comment: That is my assembly yes and the method is implemented (otherwise I'd see a compile time error telling me the interface has not been implemented). There are no libraries in the GAC as far as I can see.

Comment: The IIS configuration is set up for .Net 4 which is the target framework for the solution

Comment: Aha no I think @nunespascal had it right - someone had installed a lib in the GAC without me knowing it. Mystery solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there was an older version of one of the libraries in the GAC. The issue I had was the library in conflicting was the DTO one, and not those referenced in the error.

So in my instance, be more careful about what lives in the GAC!

Comment: My issue was similar. Had a post build event to gacutil the .dll. The gacutil path was wrong causing the project to still build but never update in GAC.

Comment: I think I have the same issue. how do you find the older library name in GAC? @RyanThomas

Answer (score 3):

Just an FYI...i had this same exact error. in my case it turned out to be assembly B being referenced by assembly A that was not in the GAC. the error indicated a problem with assembly A so was a bit misleading.

Comment: In my case, I had an interface in an assembly specifically for contracts that was in two locations. Only one of the locations for this assembly had been updated, but it happened that the other was the one the app loaded first and lead to this exception.

Comment: How do you find Assembly B Name?